# two C questions

Tags: c, pointers, graph, ellipse

1)(pointer) What is %p used for? To show the address or something else? (can you give example too?)

2) As using graph.h library and creating graphs, ellipse() function has 6 parameters. What are them? I could't find full list of them.

Thank you

**edit** sorry. it should be `<graphics.h>` library. and yes, it is an external library that wanted us to use.
ps: not homework.

Comment: "graph.h" (or "graphics.h") is not a library

Comment: This really should be two different questions, one about `%p` and one about graphics.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some web searching indicates that `graphics.h` is a Borland extension, and it does indeed contain an `ellipse` function that takes six arguments.

I found some documentation here: http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/cs1300/doc/bgi/ellipse.html

You should be aware that this functionality is not standardized, so other C implementations may not have it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `%p` is used to print out a pointer's value (the address) using `printf`:

   ```
   printf("%p", &printf); //Prints out the address of the 'printf' function
   ```
2. I have no idea what `graph.h` you're referring to, and I doubt many others do either; could you post more information on what that library is for?

Comment: sorry. it should be <graphics.h> library. to draw shapes using c/c++ with functions line(), circle(), ellipse etc.

Comment: The `&` is not needed for functions. Their bare name already is an address (`&printf` looks like address of address to me)

Comment: @pmg, the name of a function decays to an address, but the `&` just makes it explicit.  I don't see a problem with it - the same thing works for arrays.

Comment: Note that the pointer argument to printf _must_ be cast to `void *`, and there is no guarantee that you can do this with function pointers.

Comment: @Carl: I just don't like the `&` for functions, no problem with it otherwise. For arrays it matters though. Suppose you have `int a[100]`, the types of `/*decayed*/a` and `&a` are respectively `int*` and `int (*)[100]`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework, since graph.h is none of the less-than-twenty standard headers. So we could only guess what the ellipse function takes as parameters. Maybe it's x, y, width, height, start_angle, angle. Maybe it's left, top, right, bottom, start_angle, end_angle. Who knows?

The %p is for printing the string representation of a pointer, which is usually called the object's address. So yes, what you write sounds correct.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure what %p means in regards to a pointer, but you use *p to deference a pointer (get its value), and you use &y to assign a variable to a pointer (see Mehrdad's answer for printf usage).

int y =9;
int* x = &y;

2) There is no default "graph.h" library.  Are you using boost or mingw?